# How to check unused plugins of activated plugins?

Tags: wordpress

I have one wordpress site and there are too many activated plugins.
So I want to know which plugins I can deactivate. 
Is there any plugin for it or should I check one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely check one by one and regressively examine your site to ensure there aren't any issues. Plugins can do a million things both on the front and back ends, and risk is only multiplied when multiple plugins interact with each other. So, it's highly unlikely there will ever be a plugin just to say "OK" to you deactivating select ones. Way to much complex unpredictability.

Comment: Thanks. So do I have to deactivate one by one and check if it's working?

Comment: Yup, I would 1) First make sure you broadly knows what each plugin does. 2) Deactivate that plugin in the admin. 3) Use your site and determine if there were any negative consequences. 

Just keep in mind that these consequences probably won't only manifest themselves on the front end. Play with the admin, make sure everything works, etc. It's risky, but doable.

Comment: Thanks Alex, if possible, would you anwser this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528487/405-not-allowed-in-duplicator-wordpress-plugin